# Grunt server no error, not working

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

Grunt is not giving me an error, but when I navigate to the ip address, there is nothing there.

I know node works, because I used node to create a barebones server, and it serves at the same port and works just fine.

When I try to run grunt while the barebones server is running, it says that port is taken, so I know it at least thinks it's serving at that port.

When I used the same files on my local machine, it works just fine, and I can navigate to the port and it works. So does the barebones server.

Any clues as to what could be causing this? By the way, I'm using yo to install angular-bootstrap.

For the barebones server, I just do this:

```
DIR=~/proj2/www
FILE=hello.js
mkdir -p $DIR
cat <<EOF >$DIR/$FILE
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.end("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>");
});

server.listen(9000);
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from 
hostname: 'localhost'
```

Well, as the code comment says, you just have to change 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0'.

Thanks, me; you've been very helpful!